# i cant access to value of a getterFunction on pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js

the function seems like work well and i can see the value but cant access to  [this getter function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcNzL.png)

i write this code to setup store [value exist but can access to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NxPB.jpg)

```
this store:
const pro = ref()
const getProductList = computed(() => pro.value)

const getProducts = (val1 = 'newest', val2 = '', val3 = 0, val4 = 0, val5 = 0, val6 = '', val7) => {
  pro.value = null
  axios.get('', {
      params: {
        sort: val1,
        title: val2,
        flash_id: '',
        max_price: val3,
        min_price: val4,
        available: val5,
        category_id: val6,
        vip: 0,
        attribute_value_id: [val7]
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      pro.value = res.data.data.products
      console.log(pro.value)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

and this console.log getter :
[The red line below the value is unavailable ][1]
```

when i try to enter its null

Comment: You say you can't access data but you haven't shown how. The screenshot (which should be posted as [text not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)) shows the data, so how is it not accessible? Where is the code that's trying to access it and failing? If you're attempting to use the store in another component, you need to show that code.  You also need to show all relevant pinia code.  [Getters need to be returned](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Setup-Stores) from setup stores, like anything else, and you've not shown whether or not you're doing that.

Comment: what does `cant access` mean? do you get an error?

Comment: @JaromandaX X  no i dont  get error  with this code getProductsList.value   i try to enter to it but its null

Comment: perhaps `const getProductList = computed(() => pro.value)` is accessed using `getProductList.value` not `getProductsList.value`

Comment: It was a shot in the dark - you know how many questions are closed as typos?

Comment: @JaromandaX dude its typing misstake i mean getProductList when i console.log it its show the value but when i want to enter to it its null     check below picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NxPB.jpg

Comment: It was a shot in the dark - you know how many questions are closed as typos?

Comment: @JaromandaX its my fault,  now what can i do for this to enter the value